# How to get the PCM vector values during the audio recording?

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming, audio-recording, pcm

I am trying to get the array of PCM data values from the audio that is being recorded by the microphone.. and then, send it to a server, but I am not understanding how to get this data. I've tried to find some tip on the "speakHere"sample, but it was not helpful to me, I don't want any information from the audio packet, just the PCM data values.. Does anyone have an idea?
It's not from a file, I need to get the audio from microphone, get the array and send it..

As the speakHere is too complex.. I tried another solution..

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

[session addInput:audioInput];



AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioOutput = [[[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init] autorelease];
[session addOutput:audioOutput];

// Configure your output. 
dispatch_queue_t audioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("audioQueue", NULL);
[audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioQueue];
dispatch_release(audioQueue);
```

and this implementation calls this method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

but the problem is that this output is being generated with this configuration:

**mSampleRate: 44100.000000
mFormatID: 'lpcm' 
mBitsPerChannel: 16**

But I need 8000 sampleRate with 8 bitsPerChannel.

So.. how to convert or compress it??

Answer (score 0):

The buffer given the the Audio Queue record callback function can be just a C array of PCM data values.  Apple's SpeakHere sample apps shows how to configure the Audio Queue data format, and how to receive the buffer.  The sample app then saves this PCM data to a file, but you can do anything you want with the data instead (queue it up for playback, DSP analysis, music visualization, custom compression, network transmission, etc.)

An alternative is to use the Audio Unit RemoteIO callback to capture similar C arrays of PCM values, as recorded from the same mic, but with slightly lower latency and slightly greater complexity to set up.  See Apple's aurioTouch sample app for example source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hptpaw2 .. I've tried to understand the SpeakHere sample, to use the parts that I need, but I am not that good developer.. I really didn't understand the code..

Comment: @hotpaw2 : can you help me out to modify the code of speakhere in a way that , I want to extract the data from the callback and I dont want to write them on file but want to keep them in a memory i.e in a byte array or so. I am unaware of how to extract buffer data and append those data to byte array

Comment: There may already be Q&As on this site regarding how to copy structs, ints or bytes from one C array to another.  If not, ask it as a new question (not here in the comment section).